# SQL server Error [ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'username'] SQL SERVER CON NODEJS using MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, login, npm, mssql

**La configuración de la conexión:**

```
//importando la base de datos
import sql from "mssql";

//configurando la base de datos
const dbSettings = {
    user: "antony",
    passwrod: "nicodemo24",
    server:"localhost",
    database:"Conectica-sac",
    options: {
        encrypt: false, // para azure
        trustServerCertificate: true, //para el modo desarrollo
    }
}
sql.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err.message)
})
//creando una funcion para probar la conexion a la base de datos
async function getConnection() {
    //conectarse a la base de datos
    const pool = await sql.connect(dbSettings);
    // esto seria la consulta
    const result = await pool.request().query('SELECT 1');
    //lo imprimo
    console.log(result);
}

getConnection();
```

El error que me vota al ejecutarlo

> ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'username'.
> at connectListener (C:\Users\conec\Documents\antony-git\node-rest-api\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17)
> at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\conec\Documents\antony-git\node-rest-api\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:1763:9)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:652:26)
> at Connection.emit (node:events:537:28)
> at Connection.emit (node:domain:482:12)
> at Connection.emit (C:\Users\conec\Documents\antony-git\node-rest-api\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:1906:18)
> at C:\Users\conec\Documents\antony-git\node-rest-api\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:3372:18
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
> code: 'ELOGIN',

Comment: ¿Puedes acceder a esa DB con las credenciales desde algún programa de gestión de BDs?

Comment: si puedo ingresar desde el mismo sql server con las credenciales, pero cuando lo ingreso por la configuración del npm mssql me vota ese error, a pesar de que las credenciales son las correctas

Comment: ¿Hay algún otro lugar donde estés utilizando `username` ?

Comment: actualmente esta solo corriendo en sqlserver

Comment: A estas alturas solo me queda jugar la carta de "elimina todo node_modules" y dale un `npm install`.

Comment: Voy a probar  o en todo caso crearé un proyecto similar desde cero

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.